# iPhone podcast app for binge listening to large back catalog?

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts

Can anyone help me find an iphone podcast app that has features that allow efficient browsing through podcasts with large back catalogs? Specifically I would like to be able to go through the list of all episodes of a podcast and choose which ones to download and IMPORTANTLY to remove the episodes I don't want to listen to so I don't have to read through the same 500 episode descriptions every single time I choose episodes. I used to use Instacast which had this feature but has recently gone out of business and stopped functioning.

I've tried Overcast and Apple's Podcasts app so far, but neither has a feature to remove episodes I don't want from the list (as far as I can tell). I'd rather not spend $4 per app to find out the majority of them can't do this.

Thanks,
P.